# Shell syntax, how to patch bad highlight groups

Tags: syntax-highlighting, shell, color, syntax

The neovim syntax for shell scripts doesn't check if keywords like `echo`, `done`, `exit` etc.. are surrounded by blank spaces or if they're part of a bigger Word.

This results in the following bad highlighting

[image]

How can I patch it? I know I probably need to create a file in `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/sh.vim`, but what should I put inside it?

Comment: It *looks* like the syntax in nvim for the `sh.vim` *might* be using the `syn keyword echo`, which matches the keywords specified and has the highest highlighting priority.  I would try adding `syn match TestKeyword "\s*echo\s\+"` and then add `hi def link TestKeyword Comment` and see if that helps.  I tried to reproduce in ViM and couldn't.

Comment: That leaves `echo_foo` as it is in the screenshot, while `echo` gets the same highlighting as comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is happening because your [`'iskeyword'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27) did not include "_" as a valid keyword character when the syntax was first loaded.

The syntax for `sh` (among many other languages) use the [`:syn keyword` command](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-keyword) to define syntax based on keywords, and *where* the keywords are recognized (regarding the delimiters around them) depends on the `'iskeyword'` setting by default.

To track down where "_" was removed from `'iskeyword'`, you can find where it was last set with the following command:

```
:verbose set iskeyword?
```

This should show you the current setting (where you'll notice it's missing `_` in the list) and also the file and line number of the script where it was last set (which hopefully will be the place where `_` was removed.)

If you fix it back with `:set iskeyword+=_`, you'll still have to reload the syntax (easiest is by using `:set ft=sh`) for it to highlight the keywords correctly.

---

There is also a [`:syn iskeyword` command](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-iskeyword) to override the global `'iskeyword'` settings when interpreting syntax keyword elements.

The syntax file for `filetype=sh` [*does* set a specific `:syn iskeyword`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/syntax/sh.vim#L91,L98) (thanks @ChristianBrabandt for pointing it out!) But it uses the value of the `'iskeyword'` setting in its definition. (It uses the `:syn iskeyword` command to add `-` and `:` to a keyword definition for syntax purposes.)

You can override the `:syn keyword` definition by creating a new `syntax/sh.vim` file in your local Vim `after/` directory (`~/.vim/after/syntax/sh.vim`, or `~/config/nvim/after/syntax/sh.vim` for NeoVim), with the following line in its contents:

```
syntax iskeyword @,48-57,_,192-255,-,:
```

This hardcodes the default `'iskeyword'` settings, which include the "_" as a keyword character, and also includes the modifications of the shipped syntax for `sh` which adds `-` and `:`.

Comment: Is there a way to let `iskeyword` contain `_` while at the same time considering `_` as a word delimiter (I'd like to stop at `_` when I press `w`).

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it by adding `syntax iskeyword @,48-57,192-255,_,-` to `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/sh.vim`.

Comment: the recommended way for runtime syntax plugins is to use `:syn iskeyword` setting and do not mess with the 'iskeyword' option. Because it doesn't mess with word motions etc. Any syntax file that still uses the old version of setting the 'iskeyword'  option, should be fixed

Comment: @filbranden it looks like the syntax script does setup the `syn iskeyword` thing: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/9987fb0b4b591e6450fb1dfbe8f615f365057f2a/runtime/syntax/sh.vim#L102-L107  is that wrong?

Comment: @Christian Ah, good catch! It's setting it, but using `&iskeyword` in the setting. Perhaps it should fully set it explicitly? Problem is if you have `:set iskeyword-=_`, you'll have the same problem as the OP.

Comment: @filbranden I see. Will contact Charles

Comment: Thanks @Christian!

Comment: Updated the answer to incorporate @ChristianBrabandt's findings.